# Which Hindu Scriptures provides knowledge about Nagamani(Cobra Pearl)?

Tags: naga

I have heard many people saying Nagamani is obtained from  a naga type of snake and my questions are as follows:

1)  What are the rules for a snake to give nagamani?

2) What happens when the snake spits the nagamani out of its hood?

3) Is there a original nagamani in the world ?

As per [this](http://www.occulttreasures.com/cobra_pearl.html) page:

> **Most People believe Naga Mani Generally forms in the hood of a cobra
>   or king cobra. Actually it is not formed in the poison gland., but the
>   higher cobra spirit of Naga Loka, chooses one highly special,
>   spiritual and magical stone for itself. One is very lucky to get such
>   a unusual gem of Naga Loka. Naga Mutya or Naga Manikya stone is
>   blessing of Naga gods**. It blesses one with the magical fortune and
>   good luck. **The snake god which hold this pearl belong to Vasuki race
>   according to Bruhat Samhita of the great Varaha Mihira**. This mani
>   creates magic in your life. This rare magical item is only the wealth
>   of Naga Loka. Naga Land, India, is the only place on earth which has
>   relation with Naga Loka.
>
> A state of India known as Nagaland is famous for this Mani. Sometimes
>   we come across normal stones in forest which is a Naga Mani. **An expert
>   shaman only acquire it by spiritual vision. No body can get it by
>   killing a cobra.**
>
> Maha Naga Mani: Anyone possessing such a Naga Mani or cobra stone
>   attains piety, rare good fortune, and eventually becomes illustrious
>   as a leader of men, complete with a great collection of all precious
>   gems. King Vikramaditya, Raja Bhoj, King Solomon and many other Indian
>   kings, possessed such a precious treasure.

Question 4-In which Hindu Scripture do we find more details regarding these Nagamanis or Cobra Pearl?

Comment: "I seen in **many places saying** nagamani is got by a naga type of snake" -- what places? You need to cite at least one such source to make it a valid question.

Comment: kunambatty matam(temple) has it and it is very bright and it shines over 20 metres friend

Comment: friend can you give me the name of the scriptures about the nagamani and nagas  I have searched in many sites but they have only information that nagamani or pearl of naga is precious and increases wealth there is no scriptures in it so only I am asking for your help

Comment: @sakthi Hi,i like the way u address me as friend each time :)...Now as regards nagamani u can see [this](http://www.occulttreasures.com/cobra_pearl.html)..The page is having a whole lot information about those manis(Cobra pearls)..And as regards scriptural mention of the manis the page cites Varahamihira and also from the Garuda Purana..

Comment: Editing the question as suggested in the above comment might improve the chances of re-opening this question as well as getting answers.

Comment: @sakthi I have edited ur question..Give me a feedback if u are ok with it or not?

Comment: @rickross yes  and thank you for your help

Comment: Am so into this kind of stuff  Thx for making this topic 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am providing the partial answer to your question no.4 - "In which Hindu Scripture we find more details regarding these Nagamanis or Cobra Pearl?"

The answer to this question is found in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana.(Skanda 5 Chapter 24) SB 5.24: The Subterranean Heavenly Planets.**[Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24)

---

> उपर्णितं भूमेर्यथासंनिवेशावस्थानमवनेरप्यधस्तात 
>  सप्त भुविवरा
> एकैकशो योजनायुता॥7॥
>
> Beneath this earth are **seven other planets, known as Atala, Vitala,
> Sutala, Talātala, Mahātala, Rasātala and Pātāla.** I have already
> explained the situation of the planetary systems of earth. The width
> and length of the seven lower planetary systems are calculated to be
> exactly the same as those of earth.
>
> [**SB 5.24.7**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/7)
>
> ---
>
> यत्र ह वाव न भयमहोरात्रदिभि: कालविभागैरूपलक्ष्यते॥11॥
>
> **Since there is no sunshine** in those subterranean planets, time is not divided into days and nights, and consequently fear produced by
> time does not exist.
>
> [**SB 5.24.11**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/11)
>
> ---
>
> यत्र हि महाहिप्रवरशिरोणय: सर्वं तम: प्रबाधन्ते ॥12॥
>
> **Many great serpents reside there with gems on their hoods, and the effulgence of these gems dissipates the darkness in all directions.**
>
> [**SB 5.24.12**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/12)
>
> ---
>
> ततोsधस्ता तत्पाताले नागलोकपतयो वासुकिप्रमुखा: शकन
> शङ्खकुलिकमहाशंडख़श्वेतधञ्जय धृतराष्ट्रशंडख़चूडकम्बलाश्वतरदेवदत्तादयो
> महाभोगिनो महमर्षा निवासन्ति येषामु ह वै पंश्चसप्तदशशतसहस्राशीर्षाणाम
> फणासु  विरचिता **महामणयो** रोचीष्णव पातालविवरतिमिरनिकरं स्वरोचिषा
> विधमन्ति ॥31॥
>
> Beneath Rasātala is another planetary system, known as Pātāla or
> **Nāgaloka**, where there are many demoniac serpents, the masters of Nāgaloka, such as Śaṅkha, Kulika, Mahāśaṅkha, Śveta, Dhanañjaya,
> Dhṛtarāṣṭra, Śaṅkhacūḍa, Kambala, Aśvatara and Devadatta. The chief
> among them is **Vāsuki**. They are all extremely angry, and **they
> have many, many hoods — some snakes five hoods, some seven, some ten,
> others a hundred and others a thousand. These hoods are bedecked with
> valuable gems, and the light emanating from the gems illuminates the
> entire planetary system of bila-svarga.**
>
> [**SB 5.24.31**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/31)

---

So from above shlokas we come to know that those Nagas or great serpent's live under the earth's surface in different lokas .They possess the hoods upon which these gem's are found.

**Note** - I will also try to find answer's of other questions as well as description (if found)from scriptures.