# Does Nagamani really exist in Kaliyuga?

Tags: history, naga, epics

I am coming from this question: [Which Hindu Scriptures provides knowledge about Nagamani(Cobra Pearl)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16338/which-hindu-scriptures-provides-knowledge-about-nagamanicobra-pearl)

Is there a place where we can witness this Nagamani if it really exist. There are scammers coming with such Nagamanis and collecting a lot of money.

Can someone confirm if this really exist or not today? Puranas may quote about this, but today in Kaliyuga, is this true?